# MQTT Sub and Publish on same project

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt

I designed a MQTT  project on localhost, with Python Tkinter UI. I have a textbox there. When I click publish button, I want my "subclient" to subscribe the defined topic, and after subscribing, i want my another client "pubclient" to recognize the message comes from pubclient and trigger a function.

I did something wrong but cant figuere out. No errors.

```
       def func_sendanswer():

            def func_on_message(client, userdata, mesaj):
                print("Gelen Mesaj:")  
                print(mesaj)
                print("")

                conn = psycopg.connect("dbname=MQTTDB user=postgres host='localhost' password='dbpassword")
                cur = conn.cursor()

                cur.execute('INSERT INTO answers(answercontent, creatorid, topicid, createddate) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,current_timestamp)', (mesaj, online_userid, topicid))
                conn.commit()
                cur.close()        
                conn.close()

                func_refreshconversation()
    
            subclient= paho.Client("subscriber") #create client object 
            subclient.on_message=func_on_message
            
            print("connecting to broker host","localhost")
            subclient.connect("localhost")#connection establishment with broker
            print("subscribing begins here")    
            subclient.subscribe(string_topicname)#subscribe topic

            def func_refreshconversation():
                conn = psycopg.connect("dbname=MQTTDB user=postgres host='localhost' password='dbpassword'")
                cur = conn.cursor()

                cur.execute("SELECT answercontent, creatorid, createddate FROM answers WHERE topicid ='"+ str(temp[0]) +"';")
                temp2 = cur.fetchall()

                text_conversation.delete("1.0","end")

                for row in temp2:
                 
                    text_conversation.insert(END, "\n" + "Kullanıcı ID: " + str(row[1]) + "\n" + "\n" + str(row[0]) +"\n" + "Tarih: " + str(row[2]) + "\n" + "___________________________________________________" + "\n")

                cur.close()        
                conn.close()

            pubclient= paho.Client("publisher") #create client object
            mesaj = text_sendmessage.get('0.0', 'end')
            ret= pubclient.publish(string_topicname,mesaj)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should only have one client, it can both subscribe and publish at the same time.

Second you need to start the paho client [network loop](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#network-loop). If you don't start the loop then you will never receive any messages or be able to send any message larger than a single packet.

Comment: My project is a little different. I dont want it to write loop.forever, is there any way to make it listen for like 5 seconds?

Comment: client= paho.Client("user") #create client object 
                client.on_message=func_on_message
                
                print("connecting to broker host","localhost")
                client.connect("localhost")#connection establishment with broker
                print("subscribing begins here")    
                client.subscribe(string_topicname)#subscribe topic
                client.loop(timeout=10.0, max_packets=5)

Comment: still cant receive, i think the mistake is on message call. Prints in there not working too

Comment: Edit the question, do not try and add code in comments

Comment: You must run the loop, the library provides several ways to do so.